# Bind9 timeout from LAN, server listening on port 53

Tags: bind, linux-networking, ubuntu-16.04

I have a very wierd situation with Bind9 on Ubuntu Xenial. The server is listening on port 53 (tested with `portqry` from windows boxen that are trying to use it as a local DNS server) but it's timing out on requests like:

```
> dig @192.168.1.6 YYY +search

; <<>> DiG 9.11.0-P3 <<>> @192.168.1.6 YYY +search
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Search-domain is set properly on windwos (ISC DHCP makes sure of that). However, as I said, `portqry` probing port 53 says it's listening.

```
> portqry -n 192.168.1.6 -o 53

Querying target system called:

192.168.1.6

Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...

Failed to resolve IP address to name

querying...

TCP port 53 (domain service): LISTENING
```

Oddly still, server responds to queries on local host (from the server itself):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @192.168.1.6 YYY +search
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23454
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;YYY.mydomain.tld.      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
YYY.mydomain.tld. 3600  IN      A       192.168.1.11

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mydomain.tld.    3600    IN      NS      DNS-SERVER.mydomain.tld.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
DNS-SERVER.mydomain.tld. 3600  IN      A       192.168.1.6

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.6#53(192.168.1.6)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 23 03:59:37 CST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 104
```

Netstat claims `named` is listening on all the usual ports/adresses:

```
~# netstat -tanpl | grep named
tcp        0      0 10.8.0.1:53             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4074/named
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.6:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4074/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4074/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4074/named
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**: by popular request here is the `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you might need to uncomment the query-source
    // directive below.  Previous versions of BIND always asked
    // questions using port 53, but BIND 8.1 and later use an unprivileged
    // port by default.

    // query-source address * port 53;

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //      0.0.0.0;
    // };
    query-source address * port 53;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { none; };
    forwarders {
            8.8.8.8;
            8.8.4.4;
            };
    forward first;
};
```

Comment: are you using iptables or any other firewall(s)?  Can you ping 192.168.1.6 from the windows machines?

Comment: In your bind config what does the `listen-on port 53 { ... }` and `allow-query     { ...}` blocks say?

Comment: @user16081-JoeT As you could see by the portqry results not only could I ping it, it listens on 53

Comment: @jscott I don't have `allow-query {..}` block, at least not in ...options, what should it look like?

Comment: @jscott Ok, so it set it to `allow-query { any; };` but still the same. Tested if syntax is ok (i.e. server started) with `systemctl status`

Comment: Something is telling me you forgot to open port 53/udp. DNS uses udp by default, and falls back to tcp when the message is bigger than a single udp frame. If you look atyour own successful dig command, it has come through udp.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so thanks to [jscott](https://serverfault.com/users/23067/jscott) and [stoned](https://serverfault.com/users/202124/stoned), for posterity, if anyone else needs to troubleshoot situation like this here are proposed steps:

1. Make sure you've opened port 53 on both TCP **and UDP**. Port scanning UDP ports is tricky so make doubleplus sure that UDP 53 shall, indeed, pass.
2. You should have `allow-query { any; };` in global section of your named configuration file (`/etc/bind/named.conf.options` on Debian/Ubuntu)
3. Check your config syntax, on `systemd` machines you can use `systemctl status bind9` and, depending on how logging of bind is setup, `journalctl -xe -u bind9` to see if the daemnon started.
4. Test resolving from both the bind host and multiple machines.